Date conversion issue in Talend tool
I am trying to load data from MySql db to Oracle database using Talend. I am able to load upto 1+L records after that I am getting below
java.sql.SQLException: HOUR_OF_DAY: 2 -> 3.
MOre details:

I am using TIMESTAMP(6) Datatype in Oracle, in MySQL we have datetime datatype.
I am using dynamic metadata concept where I will load data of nearly 60 tables using the same job. So TMAp component I cannot use.

Please help me to resolve this issue. I researched on this no proper solution I found anywhere.
I tried using all available datatypes to load the data but no use.
